# How to change allowed file types in Azure Static WebApps?

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

I have a static react app that I deployed via Github & Azure DevOps to a Static WebApp. I can access index.html and robots.txt just fine, but when I try access a file in the same folder with a different extension (.json), the webbrowser fails to GET with 404. Which file extensions are allowed, and how do I add other file extensions to the allow list?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation available [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration), the configuration for a Static Web App is defined in `staticwebapp.config.json`. You can add a section for mime types in that file.

Something like:

```
"mimeTypes": {
  ".json": "text/json"
},
...other settings
```